# Replace Nested Dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

1. I have created a nested dictionary from my sample dataframe :

```py
dict_1 = {
    "AR": {
        "tom": {"q": 1.0},
        "jerry": {"q": 1.0},
        "spike": {"q": 1.0}
    },
    "DB": {
        "goku": {"q": 1.0},
        "vegeta": {"q": 2.0},
        "gohan": {"q": 1.0},
        "trunks": {"q": 1.0},
    },
}
```

2. I have another dictionary:

```py
dict_2 = {
    "AR": {
        "tom": {"q": 1.0}
    },
    "DB": {
        "goku": {"q": 1.0}
    },
}
```

3. Now I want to check the dictionary 1 and want to replace the same values of the dict_1 which is in dict_2.
   The **output** should be :

```py
dict_3 = dict_2 + {
    "AR": {"jerry": {"q": 1.0}, "spike": {"q": 1.0}},
    "DB": {"vegeta": {"q": 2.0}, "gohan": {"q": 1.0}, "trunks": {"q": 1.0}},
}
```

Comment: I don't think your result is correct.  Given your update, wouldn't the final dict be the same as your incoming dict?  You're replacing `tom` and `goku` with the same values you started with.

Comment: Is it replace or remove? From the output it seems you are removing the common items from dict1

Comment: i am replacing the same values which is present in dict_2 and adding dict_2 to the dictionary_3.
dict_3 is a new dictionary that i created which checks dict_1 and dict_2.
dict_1 will be the main dictionary, which replaces the same values(here tom and goku) with the dictionary name(here dict_2 ).